# jQuery slideDown() and scroll to offset works on firefox but not on chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, offset, slidedown

so i have this function for scrolling to an anchor:

```
function scrolltoancora(id){
    var aTag = $("a[name='"+ id +"']");
    $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: aTag.offset().top},'slow');
}
```

and then i have another function for sliding some content that looks like this:

```
function changecontent(id1,id2) {
   var ancora="ancora"+id2;
   $(id1).slideUp();
   $(id2).slideDown();
   scrolltoancora(ancora);
}
```

what im trying to do is slideup some content then slidedown another content and then scroll to the expanded content.

for some reason firefox works but chrome dose not.
as i understand webkit browsers like chrome needs all elements loaded to get the right offset, i tried to make use of the complete parameter of slideUp/slideDown but with no result.works on ff but not on chrome.

any ideas about how this could be accomplished? thank you.

Comment: Which part doesn't work? Only the scrolling and the slideUp/Down works correctly?

Comment: Can you make js fiddle for this?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/0os9dkaa/ basically i want it to scroll the active button to the top of the viewport.

Comment: @JuhG the slideup/down works on both browsers, the scrolling to the anchor part is messed up on chrome, i logged the offset when trying to scroll on ff and on chrome and from similar positions the values are different from one to another.

Comment: apparently using complete function on slidedown seems to work on this example, i have to check my actual code better maybe something else in generating the problem